# How to Repeat Parts of Jinja2 Template

Tags: templates, jinja2

I realize a couple of similar questions on this have been asked, but they don't relate specifically to what I'm trying to do and I'm pretty much a total beginner, so the answers seem more advanced than what I think I'm expected to do.

I'm working on implementing a Jinja2 template with Python code into an html page of notes I've been keeping while taking this course.

So...

The html block I'm trying to template and repeat has the following structure:

```
<h1>Stage Number</h1>
<div class = "lesson"> 
  <h2>Lesson Number</h2> 
     <div class="concept">
       <div class="concept-title"> Title </div>
         <div class="concept-description">
           <p>Description paragraph</p>
           <p>Description paragraph</p>
         </div>
    <div class="concept-title"> Title</div>
      <div class="concept-description">
        <p>Description paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

For each stage, lesson numbers vary and each title has a varying number of description paragraphs.

My code is on Github (this is an edited version):  https://github.com/graceehayden/Stage4Udacity-Session-2/blob/master/templates/index.html

My main.py file has the template code, which is supposed to be implemented in the index.html file.

The course just sort of went over the edge on me and re-watching videos or finding other YouTube tutorials on templating isn't helping because a lot of it is more advanced than I seem to be at this point.

Any help or pointers on how to straighten the variables out so they correlate properly with the index.html file would be so appreciated. When I pretend I don't have so many inputs, I am able to make a simple single variable work and show up when I run the app, but with the complexity I have now and need, it isn't functioning.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly you currently have a template that can take some values from the `template_values` dictionary, this template can render the page like you want. However it looks like you are restricted to a fixed number of values at the moment. Is the trouble in extending this so that you can have more than one stage or lesson sent to the template?

Comment: Yes, yes it is! That is my trouble IF you're saying the code I already have up there looks correct so far, which I'm also unsure of.

Comment: OK, I asked this question MONTHS ago now and I thought I had it figured out after asking here, but couldn't get it to work. I took a break and I think I'm close, but what I have still isn't working.  I have added my project to Github:  https://github.com/graceehayden/Stage4Udacity-Session-2/blob/master/templates/index.html

Any help on why my variables defined on main.py don't work with my index.html template would be greatly appreciated.  

Thank you in advance to anyone who bothers to read through this mass of confusion and poorly formulated questions!  I'm GOING TO FINISH THIS!

Comment: In main.py `self.render("index.html", stages=stages, name=name, lessons=lessons)` I don't think there is a variable called `stages`. If the problem is any more complex than this you probably want to consider asking a new question on here by condensing your code down to just the problematic part. Also you probably want to add `*.pyc` files into your gitignore file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you mostly have the right idea with the code so far.
The big thing that is missing is that you need data types that are sequences to extend this to do what you want here.

Each lesson has a list of concepts with an associated description.

```
concept1 = {
    'name' : 'concept1',
    'description1' : 'This is the description for concept1!',
}

lesson1 = {
     'name' : 'lesson1',
     'concepts': [concept1, concept2] #the list here lets us have more than one value
}
```

Then each Stage is a data structure that contains a list of different lessons.

```
stage1 = {
     'name' : 'stage1',
     'lessons': [lesson1, lesson2],
}
```

Finally you stuff all these different stages into the `template_values`

```
template_values = {
    'stages' : [stage1, stage2],
}
```

Then you need the templating to access the nested data:

```
{% for stage in stages %}
//do things with this particular stage
    {% for lesson in stage['lessons'] %}
        //do things with this lesson
        {% for concept in lesson['concepts'] %}
            //do things with individual concepts
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: haven't tested the template yet, so might have made some mistakes accessing the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I can move past this soon and it will be glorious. Very, very, very appreciated!